# Control statement confusion in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, for-in-loop

x is an array, y is a dict which is a member of the method z. What does the '\' mean? What does this code do?

```
for x, y in \
    self.z({'yup': [10]}):
    for typex in x:
       //if statement
```

EDIT: Thank you for the help, I'm still unsure of what is being iterated over here, the part that is confusing me is the for x,y in as opposed to me usually seeing a statement for only a single variable

Comment: as an aside this works in most languages ... not just python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\` is a line continuation, allowing the statement to continue to the next line without raising an indentation error. Aside from that this is just a vanilla for loop.

Comment: what is a vanilla for loop?

Comment: @JohnSmith I used "vanilla" here as a synonym for "ordinary".

Answer (score 1):

The \ is simply a line breaker.

The code is not complete, it's just the first part of the for loop. What x in y are iterating over in the loop will depend on the method/function z.

Comment: Thanks, I added onto my answer, could you help me understand what is being iterated over now? How does the x,y in z work?